# Run-time error '1004' on WorksheetFunction.Max/Min for variable range

Tags: excel, vba, max, min

**I want to get max and min of a range within a for loop (for each row).**

Whichever solution I found on the internet either is for static range, or gives me the same error. Currently I use the following which gives `run-time error '1004'` at `xMax` line:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim xMax As Double
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

For i = 2 To 15
    xMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws1.range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 15)))
Next
```

However the following static range works:

```
xMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws1.range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(2, 15)))
```

**I tried to siplify it to 2 cells:**

Static range has no issues:

```
xMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Cells(2, 6).Value, Cells(2, 7).Value)
```

But dynamic range pops the same error:

```
For i = 2 To 15
    xMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Cells(i, 6).Value, Cells(i, 7).Value)
Next
```

How can I achieve min/max for variable range within a loop?

Comment: You didn't properly qualify the `Cells` calls: `xMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws1.range(ws1.Cells(i, 6), ws1.Cells(i, 15)))`

Comment: Don't you have to use `Next i`? And set it as an int

Comment: @David G: No, the `i` is optional - but good practise to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your initial statement after qualifying all ranges:

> ```
> xMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws1.range(ws1.Cells(i, 6), ws1.Cells(i, 15)))
> ```

When some of the cells inside the range have errors, such as `#NA` or `#DIV!0`, the `Max` function raises a error. To have your computation ignore error cells in the range, you can use the `Aggregate` function.

```
xMax = Application.Aggregate(14, 6, ws1.range(ws1.Cells(i, 6), ws1.Cells(i, 15)), 1)
```

- The first parameter `14` specifies `Large`. Use `15` for `Small`.
- The Second parameter `6` specifies *"ignore errors in the computation"*
- The last parameter `1` specifies *"First largest result"*

Notice also that the other version that you tried, i.e.

> ```
> xMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Cells(i, 6).Value, Cells(i, 7).Value)
> ```

Does not specify a continuous range but a set of values (variants). This will raise error whenever one of these variants is not numeric. But you dont need this version however.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for saving my head banging against the wall!

Comment: I used `xMax = Application.Aggregate(4, 6, ws1.range(ws1.Cells(i, 6), ws1.Cells(i, 15)))` for `Max` and `xMin = Application.Aggregate(5, 6, ws1.range(ws1.Cells(i, 6), ws1.Cells(i, 15)))` for `Min` instead of 14 for Large and 15 for Small if anyone interested in the future.

Answer (score 1):

you have to tell Excel where `cell` points to - else it will use the active sheet, for example

```
xMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws1.range(ws1.Cells(i, 6), ws1.Cells(i, 15)))
```

or

```
With ws1
    xMax =  Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(.Range(.Cells(i, 6), .Cells(i, 15)))
End With
```

personally, i usually assign a range to a range-variable first - it helps debugging:

```
With ws1
    dim r as range
    ''' set r = .Range(.Cells(i, 6), .Cells(i, 15))  ' Fails if not all cells are numeric
    set r = .Range(.Cells(i, 6), .Cells(i, 15)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
    xMax =  Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(r)
End With
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. However I have the same error when it comes to cells containing `#N/A`

Answer (score 0):

I include a split function that captures the letter easier.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim xMax As Double
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

For i = 2 To 15
    xMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws1.range("F" & i & ":" & Split(Cells(, i).Address, "$")(1) & "15"))
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, i variable is for rows not for columns. I need to get `F2:O2, F3:O3... , F15:O15`, Please note that `xMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws1.range("F:" & i & "O:" & i))` is not working either. Any ideas?